# How to store and read a byte string (PyGame image) with XML? I get ValueError or TypeError (cannot serialize).

Tags: python, string, byte, pygame

I am trying to convert a image to a string to bytes and back into an image but somewhere something is breaking and I really don't know what. I am using Python 3.3 and pygame.

The reason I need to do it to a string because later I plan on exporting the string to an XML file and the when I pull the variable it comes in a unicode string type anyways.

Any help would be appreciated for this annoying problem.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
displaysurf = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))

dirtImg = pygame.image.load('1.gif')
dirtXY= dirtImg.get_size()
print(dirtXY)

dirtText = str(pygame.image.tostring(dirtImg,'RGBX',False))



dirtBytes = bytes(dirtText, 'utf8' )
print(type(dirtBytes))
#prints out <class 'bytes'>


testimg = pygame.image.fromstring(dirtBytes, dirtXY, 'RGBX')
```

Error Information

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Derek\workspace\Test\test.py", line 18, in <module>

  testimg = pygame.image.fromstring(dirtBytes, dirtXY, 'RGBX')
      ValueError: String length does not equal format and resolution size
```

Obviously I don't change image at anytime so it must be in the encoding or decoding to bytes. If there is a better way to do then please do tell

Comment: Are you sure that the image has the 32x32 shape specified in your `pygame.image.fromstring` call?

Comment: Yes. I edited to show that it must be the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After discussion in chat with ddaniels, I found that this is the process (s)he is using:

- pygame image
- --> pygame bytestring
- --> manual copy-paste to xml
- --> read from xml
- --> pygame image (failed here)

I think copy-paste is not a general solution for others who might find this so I made a way to go full circle from the pygame image to xml and back to pygame. It is more simple in Python 2, but this code works with both Python 2 and Python 3.

If anybody knows how to simplify this process, please let me know.

```
import pygame
import base64
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
pygame.init()
dirt_image = pygame.image.load('dirt.gif')
dirt_xy = dirt_image.get_size()

# incantation starts here
# The result of tostring is a bytestring with basically binary data.
dirt_bytes = pygame.image.tostring(dirt_image, 'RGBX', False)
# b64 encode so that we have all printable characters in the string.
# Otherwise elementtree doesn't want to accept the content.
# The result is another byte string but with printable characters.
dirt_bytes_in_64 = base64.b64encode(dirt_bytes)
# in Python 3, ElementTree complains about bytestrings so we further encode
# it into utf-8. In Python 2, this is not necessary.
dirt_bytes_in_64_in_utf8 = dirt_bytes_in_64.decode('utf-8')

# ElementTree create, save, restore
root = ET.Element("root")
dirt = ET.SubElement(root, 'dirt')
dirt.set('bytes64utf8', dirt_bytes_in_64_in_utf8)
tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
tree.write('images.xml')
tree_restored = ET.parse('images.xml')
dirt_bytes_in_64_in_utf8_restored = tree_restored.find('dirt').get('bytes64utf8')

# Convert from utf-8 back to base64 bytestring.
dirt_bytes_in_64_restored = dirt_bytes_in_64_in_utf8_restored.encode('utf-8')
# Convert from base64 bytestring into the original binary bytestring
dirt_bytes_restored = base64.b64decode(dirt_bytes_in_64_restored)

# Shazam. (for me at least)
restored_image = pygame.image.fromstring(dirt_bytes_restored, dirt_xy, 'RGBX')
display_surf = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
display_surf.blit(dirt_image, (0, 0))
display_surf.blit(restored_image, (32, 32))
pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: I need to bytes because when I pass it to the xml file later it is parsed back as a string. If there is a way to parse the variable back as bytes then this would work to. Also fromstring must in bytes for format so if you did dirt_string = str(pygame.image.tostring.......) And passed the dirt_string to the from string method it would give you an error saying it doesn't accept strings

Comment: Are you working in python 3? Does the code above work for you? It works as-is for me in python 2.

Comment: I am on python 3.3 . Like I said though if you try

`dirt_string = str(pygame.image.tostring(dirt_image, 'RGBX', False))`

it doesn't work and gives the error

`TypeError: must be bytes, not str`

Comment: I just installed python 3.3 and pygame for 3.3. The code above works for me without further manipulation of the string. You can see that I was luckily correct that pygame returns a bytes string from image.tostring() rather than a unicode string. You shouldn't need to do any further modification. Please note that i removed the str() conversion that you did because that converts to a unicode string and may be what is causing your problem.

Comment: If you read the original I say that when I pass the string to the XML and parse it back later it is return as normal Unicode string. I never said I had a problem with normal string passing. I have a problem with the encoding from unicode to bytes

Comment: @ddaniels can you join me in [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39394/pygame-question-chat)?

Comment: Yes it does. I did not know of the base 64 encoding. Thank you for all your help!